# In Google Sheets, how to transpose multiple column headers and data into a single column of multiple row labels and data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Not sure what is the proper spreadsheet terminology to word this.

How to turn this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+...
|Username   |First Name |Second Name|...
+-----------+-----------+-----------+...
|Uname1     |FName1     |SName1     |...
+-----------+-----------+-----------+...
|Uname2     |FName2     |SName2     |...
+-----------+-----------+-----------+...
|Uname3     |FName3     |SName3     |...
+-----------+-----------+-----------+...
:           :           :           :
```

Into this?:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|Username   |Uname1     |
+-----------+-----------+
|First Name |FName1     |
+-----------+-----------+
|Second Name|SName1     |
+-----------+-----------+
|Username   |Uname2     |
+-----------+-----------+
|First Name |FName2     |
+-----------+-----------+
|Second Name|SName2     |
+-----------+-----------+
:           :           :
```

The ellipsis means the multiple columns/rows continues.

I tried googling transposing columns to rows, but couldn't find the exact solution to the question.

Comment: Select the whole range; Copy; Move to a new spot on the spreadsheet; Paste Special> Paste as transposed.

Comment: @Tedinoz - no, that doesn't work. Need to transpose multiple column of headers + data, all to two columns of label and data.

Comment: Apologies; I missed the subtlety of retaining two columns. And @player0 has come to the rescue with an ingenious formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A2:C<>"", "♦"&A1:C1&"♥"&A2:C, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♥"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there a way to add a new line before each new group? For instance in this example a new line before each "Username"

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.