# In Google Sheets, how to transpose multiple column headers and data into a single column of multiple rows (I Column to 1 row each)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

My question is very close to that other one:

[In Google Sheets, how to transpose multiple column headers and data into a single column of multiple row labels and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722271/in-google-sheets-how-to-transpose-multiple-column-headers-and-data-into-a-singl)

My Input (minimal example of 3 columns, but in reality 100's of columns):

| GROUP 1 | GROUP 2 | GROUP 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | b | cc |
| aaa | bb | cc |
| aaaaa | bbb | ccc |
| aa | bbb | ccc |
| a | bbb | ccc |
|  | bbb |  |
|  | bbbb |  |

Needed Output:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GROUP 1 | aa | aaa | aaaaa | aa | a |  |
| GROUP 2 | b | bb | bbb | bbb | bbb | bbb |
| GROUP 3 | cc | cc | ccc | ccc | ccc |  |

The columns need to be with dynamic ending because their lengths are irregular.

So far I've only managed to use the usual transpose method by manually transposing each columns as so:

IN COLUMN `F1:F`:

```
=transpose(A1:A)
=transpose(B1:B)
=transpose(C1:C)
etc.
```

That is an error prone and very manual process for hundreds of columns.

What way would be a more efficent process to modify @player0 's formula in linked post to suit the above use?
Your help is appreciated very much.

Comment: any reason to not go with wholesome `=TRANSPOSE(A:C)`

Comment: Amazing, that works: https://i.imgur.com/iHYTe6T.png I couldn't think of that. Just learned we can transpose multiple columns all at once (I guess the filter exception for doing that created my blindspot). Many thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide a proper response to the question, I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section.

```
=TRANSPOSE(A:C)
```

**References**

- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262